# Current Consumption

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, circuit-analysis, peltier

I have a 3S LiPo as a power source for my circuit. My load consists of a peltier cooler module, a DC fan, and a water pump all running at 12V. Now, the question is: if i incorporate a DC fan that has a higher current consumption, will it affect the current running on my peltier cooler thus affecting its performance? in that case, if I incorporate a higher current consumption water pump, will it affect the current running on my peltier too?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the arrangement of loads (if they are connected in parallel/series). Present a schematic to clarify your intentions. If loads are connected in parallel to the battery and total current consumption is below the battery's rating, then the broad answer is no, current through any specific load will not be affected by other loads. However, be mindful of sudden current spikes due to varying loads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Increasing the load on your battery, either by adding more fans and pumps or replacing the existing fans/pumps with fans/pumps that require more current, will lower the voltage available to all of these devices, including the cooler module.
The reason is that your battery is not an ideal voltage source, so as the load current increases the terminal voltage will decrease.

When operated at a lower voltage the cooler module will be less effective.

There is no free lunch here. You can add a dc/dc converter module between the battery and fan/pump/cooler to maintain the voltage but the operating time will be reduced.